# How to remove more than one elements from an array from different indexes at same time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of integers, which I'm using the `.push()` method to add to.

I know that `splice()` method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).

But is there is a way to remove multiple elements from the array at different indexes at the same time?

I know we can also use `filter()` method but The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function which I don't want.

Ex:-

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I know to remove 3 and 5 I can follow following steps:-

> 1. array.splice(2, 1);
> 2. array.splice(3, 1);

But Can I achieve this in a single step without using `splice()` method twice?

Comment: Do you know the specific values you want to remove?

Comment: You can only remove consecutive elements using `splice`

Comment: Yes of course @DeividasKaržinauskas

Comment: @Rajesh Please read and understand question

Comment: @Gauravjoshi I'm sorry if my comment was not expressive enough. I meant **No**. You cannot remove multiple disjoint elements using 1 `.splice` call. You can rather try using `.filter` or any other method

Comment: Is requirement to remove elements from existing array, or create new array with elements removed?

Comment: @guest271314 OP wants to know if you can remove `2nd` and `4th` element (*3 and 5*) using 1 splice call

Comment: Do you want to remove items based on their *values*, or their *indices*?

Comment: Do you mean `array.splice(4, 1);`?

Comment: @guest271314 - Not to remove the value `5`, because by the time the second `.splice()` runs the value `5` is at index `3`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Was noting to OP that current text of Question is  _"2. `array.splice(3, 1);`"_, where if those were actual indexes to be removed, requirement could be achieved using single call `array.splice(2, 2)`. OP could clarify this by editing Question, though does appear index `4` is what is expected to be removed.

Comment: @guest271314 - No, `array.splice(2,2)` would remove the values 3 & 4. OP wants to remove values 3 & 5, and the code shown does that. As I already said, before the second `.splice()` runs the index has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use trailing comma at destructuring assignment to select specific elements from array, assign resulting values within array to original array reference.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
{let [a,b,,c,,] = array; array = [a,b,c]};

console.log(array);
```

You can use object destructuring on an array to get only specific indexes from array

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
{let {0:a,1:b,3:c} = array; array = [a,b,c]};

console.log(array);
```

You can also use `.forEach()` to iterate an array of elements to match, `.indexOf()`, `.splice()` to remove elements which match value of element within array

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
[3, 5].forEach(p => array.splice(array.indexOf(p), 1));

console.log(array);
```

Using  `for..of` loop, `Array.prototype.findIndex()`, `Array.prototype.splice()`

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var not = [3, 5];
for (let n of not) array.splice(array.findIndex(v => v === n), 1);

console.log(array);
```

Using `for..of` loop with `Array.prototype.entries()`, `Array.prototype.some()`, `Array.prototype.splice()`

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var not = [3,5];
for (let [k, p] of array.entries()) not.some(n => !(n-p)) && array.splice(k, 1);

console.log(array);
```

You can also use `for` loop, `Object.assign()` to set indexes to keep at beginning of array, call `.splice()` with parameter set to `-` `.length` of the number of elements to remove from array

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var not = [3,5];
for (var o = {}, k = -1, i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (!not.some(n => n === array[i])) o[++k] = array[i];
}
Object.assign(array, o).splice(-not.length);

console.log(array);
```

Using `Array.prototype.reduce()` with `Object.assign()`

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var not = [3,5];
Object.assign(array, array.reduce(([o, not, k], p) => 
  [Object.assign(o, !not.some(n => n === p) ? {[++k]:p} : void 0), not, k]
  , [{}, not, -1]).shift()
).splice(-not.length);

console.log(array);
```

Another option, if the numbers are unique, is to use `Set`, `.delete()`, convert `Set` object to `Array` using rest element at destructuring assignment

```js
var array = new Set;
var not = [3, 5];
for (let n = 1; n <= 5; n++) array.add(n);

for (let n of not) array.delete(n);
[...array] = array;

console.log(array); // `array = new Set(array)`
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the exact values you want removed you can use [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

This removes more than one element from an array at different indexes at same time.

Example in your case:

```js
var filtered = [1,2,3,4,5].filter(value => { return value !== 3 && value !== 5 });

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon. You can add code snippet using it

Comment: @nnnnnn My bad :-)

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas Yes we can achieve this by the filter but The filter() method creates a new array .

Comment: @Gauravjoshi replacing an original array with new array does not work for you?

Comment: @Gauravjoshi as functional programming and immutable objects become more fashionable, we are learning that creating a new array is a better way of working.

Comment: @slim Can you define "better"?

Comment: @guest271314 In few enough words for a comment here, no. Plenty has been written about it. Try this: https://alistapart.com/article/making-your-javascript-pure

Comment: @guest271314 Does it mean that array.filter() does not achieve the results that OP asked for? Maybe you could have a look at my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501592/what-are-the-differences-in-the-outcome-array-splice-versus-let-array? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hard code when you know the specific values you need to remove and when the array is small:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
array.splice(2,3,4);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do like this in place;

```js
var          arr = [1,2,3,4,5,17,23,37,61,15],
itemsToGetRidOff = [3,17,15,1,23];
arr.reduceRight((_,e,i,a) => itemsToGetRidOff.includes(e) && a.splice(i,1),[]);
console.log(arr);
```